# Save Image From ImagePicker Locally as a Memory(cache)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to save an Image from ImagePicker  as a Memory but error Occured . Can you Please help me with this function and if another function needed to load image please Mentioned it below.

```
Uint8List? memoryImage;
  Future getImage() async {
    
     final picker = ImagePicker();
          final image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

          if (image == null) return;
          final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
          final path=directory.path;
          final Filename=basename(image.path);
          File file = File('$directory/$Filename.jpg');
        final bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
        final byte1=  file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
        

    setState(() {
      memoryImage = byte1 as Uint8List?;
    });
   
  }
```

Comment: What is the error??

Comment: Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'Directory: '/data/user/0/com.example.demoim/app_flutter'/be0154b3-922c-4ac8-9f52-e22ca0dd05984540658051800379501.jpg.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this line you can write image bytes as a file.

```
File imageFile = await File(fileSavePath).writeAsBytes(imageBytes);
```

To access the Uint8List from the file you need to use

```
Uint8List memoryImage = File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync();
```

Or

```
Uint8List memoryImage = await File(imagePath).readAsBytes();
```

here the problem in your code is you are assigning file to a Uint8List. That's the error I guess